# How to validate a line into a completePost and incompletePost

Tags: c#, winforms

I read line in a log that another program called XYX generates. I validate every line I read by using this method IsTheRowValid.
Sometimes this program XYZ write log lines that is not correct for some strange reason.

This method IsTheRowValid has been successfully validating every line correct until now. I really don't know how to change my method to make it general

The line looks like this:
line = "2016-08-16 13:10:52016-08-16 13:12:34 src:Dlg:89     message:0x00000110 
        lParam:0x00000000 wParam:0x000100a6";

A proper format for date is ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
In this case has the program XYX only written a small part(the first 18 characters) of a correct line.

I want to modify my method so the 
completePost = 2016-08-16 13:12:34 src:Dlg:89     message:0x00000110 
        lParam:0x00000000 wParam:0x000100a6;
and the 
incompletePost =  2016-08-16 13:10:5

How can I do that?

```
private static bool IsTheRowValid(string line, out string incompletePost, 
                                  out string completePost)
{
    string pattern = @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}";
    completePost = "";
    incompletePost = "";

    List<Match> myList = Regex.Matches(line, pattern).Cast<Match>
                         ().ToList();

    string temp = line.Substring(35);
    string type = temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf(":")).ToLower();

    // The row is valid containg only one ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD hh:mm:ss and 
    // the DateTime is in position 0
    if (myList.Count == 1 && myList[0].Index == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // The row is invalid because we have the ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in 
    // the wrong position
    else if (myList.Count == 1 && myList[0].Index > 0)
    {
        completePost = line.Substring(myList[0].Index);
        incompletePost = 
           line.Remove(myList[0].Index).TrimEnd().TrimStart();

        return false;
    }
    // The row is invalid because we have two occurences of ÅÅÅÅ-MM-
    // DD hh:mm:ss
    else if(myList.Count == 2)
    {
        completePost= 
           line.Substring(myList[1].Index).TrimStart().TrimEnd();
        incompletePost = line.Substring(0, 
                            myList[1].Index).TrimStart().TrimEnd();

        return false;
    }

    throw new System.ArgumentException("Unexpected condition in 
       IsTheRowValid", line);
}
```

//Tony

Comment: Can you put a little bit more effort into question? `XYX` and then `XYZ`... what is `ÅÅÅÅ`? `YYYY` ?.. Try to make clear input data (examples), wanted result and the problem..

Comment: ÅÅÅÅ is year such as 2015 or 2016 or 2017 and MM is month between 01 and 12 and DD is day in month. hh is hour mm is minute and ss is second.

Comment: XYX is just another program that we can forget for this question

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39116892/edit) own question to fix problems and add clarifications.

Comment: Sorry for using ÅÅÅÅ instead of YYYY which is the proper way for defining year